# Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\RSA' not found in laravel ssh key generate

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, rsa

Please check the code.
My code is here:

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use SSH;
use Storage;

class SSHController extends Controller
{
    public function key($key)
    {
    try {
        $rsa = new RSA();
        $rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_OPENSSH);
        $keys = $rsa->createKey(2048);
        $private = $keys['privatekey'];
        $public = $keys['publickey'];

        Storage::disk('localKeys')->put($key,$private);
        Storage::disk('localKeys')->put($key.'.pub',$public);

        return $public;
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \Log::error("Failed to generate SSH key. Error message -> ".$e->getMessage());
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Something went really wrong!"
        ],500);
    }
}
}
```

Last five hours i try but, no response.
Laravel 5.7 use in system.
Advanced Thank you, for help!

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: not working. @Tarasovych

Comment: What's the output of the command?

Comment: return $public; @Tarasovych

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal, not in the code.

Comment: yes run this `composer dump-autoload` in terminal. @Tarasovych

Comment: Remove the import, try again

Comment: ok.  @Tarasovych

Comment: Not working.. @Tarasovych

Comment: Thank you, for help! Solve this.@Tarasovych

Comment: composer install @DineshSuthar